# How do i return the logged in user with its role using Lravel Sanctum API Token and display in Vue

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, token

I am using laravel Sanctum API token . I can successfully log in the user and
I am trying to get the logged in user and the role assign to it in vue but i have no luck so far

```
 public function user(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->user();
    }
```

this is the code that returns the user how do i return the role attached to this user,
so in my vue i can do something like this to display the role

```
{{ user.role.name }}
```

User model

```
public function roles()
    {
        
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
```

Role model

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually load the roles relationship before returning the user object.

You can do so by calling `load('roles')` on the user like this:

```php
    public function user(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->user()->load('roles');
    }
```

See the documentation for details: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading

If you always need the roles when interacting with a user, you could also eager-load the relationship by setting

```php
protected $with = ['roles'];
```

on your user model.

Again, see the documentation for further reference: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading (Eager loading by default)

Comment: how do i display the roles name in the Vue , I can see that in my response if i do this response.data.roles[0].name but is there a way to display it like this in my vue {{ user.roles.name }} or even {{ roles.name}}? thanks

Comment: You're trying to render a list. Take a look at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html to see how it's done.

Comment: its not a list , it s just one user

Comment: Yes, but a list of roles on that user. That's why roles is an array